# Does Google Chrome actually run OK on Windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, 64-bit

A friend of mine is trying to run Chrome on Windows 10 but it takes ages to start and load up. I asked him to look at the app in Settings but he gets "Unavailable" when displaying Google Chrome in the Settings/Apps view. From other forums I have seen comments that 64 bit Chrome has issues on Windows 10, but 32 bit runs OK?! If we tried 32 bit Chrome, do we have to uninstall 64 bit first?
Two basic questions then - 1. Does Chrome work on Windows 10? and 2. uninstall 64 bit Chrome before installing 32 bit Chrome?

Comment: Yes; Of course it does.  Chrome 32-bit and 64-bit can exist on a single system.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 64 bit runs perfectly fine under Windows 64 bit; I use multiple machines for months.

I doubt there is any general issue in any other combination; it is probably something specific to that machine.

Comment: Cheers Aganju. Reckon you may be right as 32 bit, 64 bit Chrome and Edge are all taking over 10 minutes to load. Firefox has been installed and is fine.